# How to display different image on click of three div in wicket?

Tags: java, html, wicket

I am new to apache wicket. I need to display a default image for a div in wicket. On click of left side of image i want to replace it other image and for right side of the click i want to replace it with another image.

For this I came up with following html and java codes:

```
<html>
<head>
    <title>Wicket Hello World</title>
    <style>
        #linkDecisionContainer.left{
            background-image: url("Desert.jpg");
        }

        #linkDecisionContainer.default{
            background-image: url("Koala.jpg");
        }

        #linkDecisionContainer.right{
            background-image: url("Penguins.jpg");
        }

    </style>
</head>
<body>    
    <div wicket:id ="linkDecisionContainer">
        <a wicket:id="leftChoice"></a>
        <a wicket:id="defaultChoice"></a>
        <a wicket:id="rightChoice"></a>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

I tried to add default class to a WebMarkupContainer and on the click event i added left and right classes accordingly.

```
public class Hello extends WebPage {

private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
WebMarkupContainer ldc=new WebMarkupContainer("linkDecisionContainer");

private AjaxLink left;
private AjaxLink right;

public Hello() {

    super();

    ldc.add(new AttributeModifier("class", true, new Model<String>("default")));

    left = new AjaxLink("leftChoice") {
        private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

        @Override
        public void onClick(AjaxRequestTarget target) {
            switchView("left");
            target.addComponent(right);
        }
    };

    right = new AjaxLink("rightChoice") {
        private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

        @Override
        public void onClick(AjaxRequestTarget target) {
            switchView("right");
            target.addComponent(right);
        }
    };

    add(left);
    add(right);

}


    private void switchView(String viewName) {
        if (viewName.equals("left")) {
            ldc.add(new AttributeModifier("class", true, new Model<String>("left")));
        } 
        else if (viewName.equals("right")) {
            ldc.add(new AttributeModifier("class", true, new Model<String>("right")));
        }
    }

}
```

Could anyone please guide me to achieve it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From the code you provided it looks like you don't refresh the "linkDecisionContainer". Additionally you shouldn't add more and more `AttributeModifier` classes but instead just change the value of the underlying model. The `AttributeModifier` won't be replaced by adding another one. Therefore you're relying on the Implementation of `Behaviors` to determine which Modifier acutally wins.

```
    private IModel<String> ldcClassModel;

public Hello() {
    super();

    ldcClassModel = Model.of("default");
    final WebMarkupContainer ldc = new WebMarkupContainer("linkDecisionContainer");
    add(ldc);
    ldc.setOutputMarkupId(true);
    ldc.add(new AttributeModifier("class", ldcClassModel));

    AjaxLink left = new AjaxLink("leftChoice") {
        private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

        @Override
        public void onClick(AjaxRequestTarget target) {
            ldcClassModel.setObject("left");
            target.addComponent(ldc);
        }
    };
    AjaxLink right = new AjaxLink("rightChoice") {
        private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

        @Override
        public void onClick(AjaxRequestTarget target) {
            ldcClassModel.setObject("right");
            target.addComponent(ldc);
        }
    };

    add(left);
    add(right);

}
```